# Net Present Value

Tags: finance

You run a construction firm.  You have just won a contract to construct a government building.  It will take one year to construct it, requiring an investment of $9.78$ million today and $5$ million in one year.  The government will pay you $22.5$ million upon the building's completion.  Suppose the cash flows and their times of payment are certain, and the risk-free rate is 11%.

1. What is the NPV of this opportunity?
2. How can your firm turn this NPV into cash today?

For #1 I solved the NPV by taking PV(Benefits) - PV(costs) = $\frac{22.5}{1.11}$ - $9.78 -$$\frac{$5}{1.11}$ = $6 million.  Is this correct?

For #2, I am not sure what they mean.  I am guessing it involves borrowing money today?  Any help here?  Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I don´t know what kind of calculator  you possess but $\frac{22.5}{1.11} - 9.78 -\frac{5}{1.11}=5.9858\approx 6$

Answer (score 1):

For 1, you have the correct calculation but the final answer is wrong.  For 2, I think they want you to say you could borrow $9.78$ plus the NPV now and pay off the loan plus the $5$ at the end of the year out of the $22.5$ payment.

Answer (score 0):

Part II

I think Ross is almost right but here is one way you can present.

[image]

Comment: I can't see your note or image.

Comment: I will report, give me a minute